# Allophones and Intonation transcripts

Tags: discussion, american-english, pronunciation, ipa

I bump into [this website](https://fonetika.ff.cuni.cz/studium/stranky-kurzu/english-phonetics-phonology/transcription-exercises/) on Google, and it has pretty good examples of IPA transcripts with allophones and intonation; however, I could not find such elsewhere.

I am grateful for the recommendations that have similar things preferably in American accent.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can try the [George Mason Accent Archive](https://accent.gmu.edu/).